# Kinetics for E1cb reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, kinetics, elimination

We were taught that the kinetics of a reaction is determined by the reactions ‘rate determining step’ which is also the slowest step of the reaction. For E1 as well as E2 reactions the slowest steps are easily determined by the mechanism and I derived the rate laws for those.

In the case of E1cb reactions, which step can be taken as the slowest step?

Is it the one in which the acidic hydrogen is extracted by the base or is it the one where the elimination takes place (carbanion intermediate)?

Comment: I would think that this depends on the substrate.

Comment: See my answer here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/105485/44877

Comment: @TanYongBoon oh ok so the rate is proportional to the [R-X] only right?

Comment: @SomV.Tambe Since the rate-determining step involves both C-H bond breaking, wouldn't both base concentration and substrate concentration be factored in?

Comment: @TanYongBoon but then why is the reaction known as Unimolecular?

Comment: @SomV.Tambe May I know where you heard that from?

Comment: @TanYongBoon https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/E1cB-elimination_reaction

Comment: I just checked. According to Carey & Sundberg (2007) Advanced Organic Chemistry, the E1cB mechanism involves second order kinetics. And I think it makes perfect sense as E1cB involves both base and the substrate reacting in the formation of the carbanion intermediate. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Did you even read the section of the wikipedia page on chemical kinetics of E1cB? I think there is clearly a line stating that the reaction follows second order kinetics.